# Which terms in web design are 'real' vs 'abstracted'?

Tags: database, web-hosting, terminology, abstraction

I'm currently building a website. I have no prior experience and no formal instruction beyond reading things on the internet. I have a background in physics and math, and experience with programming. I am trying to approach this in a very bottom-up way, since that is how I've had the most success in the past, but am hindered by the preponderance of relevant terms that are difficult to find precise, non-abstract definitions for. For example, I'd been under the impression that 'server' referred solely to the physical machine on which a 'website' (collection of html, php etc. files) is 'hosted' (stored in such a way that they can be requested over the internet), and only recently found out that, rather than being a matter of setting permissions or connection settings, access to these files is granted by a program, also called a 'server', running on the machine.

Unfortunately it seems that most websites discussing these sorts of things are either very non-technical or assume a fair degree of familiarity with the terminology at the outset. Specifically, the questions I have at this point are:

What is a 'database'? Is it distinct from 'a collection of data' in any non-abstract way?

and

What does a thing (program?) like 'MySQL' do? Is it a program? A language? An abstraction of a data management protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Server can refer to the hardware your website runs on.  Hardware today is as much of a commodity as rice or wheat is.  So most of the time server refers to the software that is serving your website up.

A database is any data your keeping.  Mostly, that's kept in a relational database management system (ie: database).  MySQL is one RDBMS.  Postgres is another, as is Oracle.  They commonly use a language called "SQL", Structured Query Language.

You need a database if you're going to keep any type of data for your website.  If you're only serving up static web pages, then you don't need one.  If you're going to be managing users, or keeping any type of information, a database server can make that much much easier.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me a lot of useful terms. So 'database' is abstract, defined by how other programs interact with it, but 'relational database management system' is not, and refers to programs such as MySQL, which is distinct from the language 'SQL', which I'm pretty sure codifies a data management protocol.

Comment: SQL is really closer to a language that a protocol.  Typically a database will determine it's own protocol, and pushes SQL across it.  In whatever programming language your using, there should be a driver for it so you can access the database.